# How to make words inside of the Div disappear when mouse scrolled by the user?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Does anyone knows how to make some words disappear inside the div when the user scrolled the mouse like on this website http://couleecreative.com/. In this case I want to make effect like "Hello, we're coulee creative". whether using css3 or jquery, I really appreciate it if you would show me. I am sorry I am amateur on web design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the example you have presented gradually changes the opacity i suggest a solution where a calculation takes place based on the window scroll position and the element position that you want to hide. For example,

http://jsfiddle.net/dva2H/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var elemSelector = "#header-content";
    $(window).scroll(function (e) {
        var elemTop = $(elemSelector).offset().top;
        var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elemSelector).height();
        var windowPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(windowPos>=elemTop){
            $(elemSelector).css("opacity",(elemBottom-windowPos<0?0:elemBottom-windowPos)/elemBottom);
        }else{
            $(elemSelector).css("opacity",1);
        }

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$(window).scroll(fn)
```

to get scroll events for the window.

---

You can examine the value of:

```
$(window).scrollTop()
```

to see whether the scroll position is at the top of not.

---

Then, you can use `.hide()` or `.show()` or some other resize option to hide or show content in the page based on the scroll position.

Here's a simplified example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/QZy55/

Comment: You were trying to show me how to make  the header part, but I was asking how to disappearing the title word : "Hello, we're coulee creative We craft custom websites for entrepreneurs, organizations and established brands.
Have an idea? We're here to help."

Comment: @TiffanyDiamanta - if you are more specific in your question, you are more likely to get specific answers that match your desire.  You didn't say you wanted to make a specific set of words disappear.  Instead, you wanted us to try to figure out what effect was happening on that web site.  Oh well, it looks like you already got your answer.

Comment: Ok I am sorry @jfriend00

Answer (score 0):

I believe the technique is called Parallax Scrolling, there are several resources out there that have examples of this (if you just Google "Parallax Scrolling") and tutorials such as this one: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/

Comment: yeah I know how to make parallax scrolling (In simple way of course)but the effect I asked seem not the part of the parallax scrolling technique

Comment: @TiffanyDiamanta I see, sorry about that then. I will revisit this question later this evening and I will try to provide a better answer if it's not answered by then.